# How to update a model inside an exception of a view function and make the transaction commit to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

We are trying to create a model to control the number of Access attempts of a user, and then make a call to a function that might throw an exception when, for example, the credentials are not valid.
If there is an exception, update the model by incrementing the attempts by one, otherwise update the model in a different way.
Everytime we are in the exception branch the model doesn't get created, nor updated.
We have tried using

```py
    s1 = transaction.savepoint()
    transaction.savepoint_commit(s1) 
and @transaction.non_atomic_requests
```

but the result gets discarded anyway.
There is no way to avoid the exception logic. Django version: Django==2.2.24

`access_attempt.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class AccessAttempt(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=255, null=True, db_index=True)

    failures_since_start = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Failed Logins"))
```

`validate_jwt_auth.py`

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from .models.access_attempt import AccessAttempt
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def obtain_tokens(request, credentials):
    attempt = AccessAttempt.objects.filter(username=credentials['username']).first()
    if attempt is None:
        attempt = AccessAttempt.objects.create(
            username=credentials['username'],
            failures_since_start=0
        )
        attempt.save()
    failures = attempt.failures_since_start
    print(failures)
    if failures > 5:
        return {'message': "Failed too many times"}, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            payload = TokenObtainPairSerializer(context={'request':request}).validate(credentials)
            attempt.failures_since_start=0
            attempt.save()
            return payload, status.HTTP_200_OK
    except AuthenticationFailed:
        attempt.failures_since_start += 1
        attempt.save()
        print(attempt.failures_since_start)
        return {'message': "Unauthorized"}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
```

`views.py`

```py
def generate_auth(request):
    b = json.loads(request.body)
    if b['username'] is None or b['password'] is None:
        return JsonResponse({'message': "Bad Request"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    payload, status = obtain_tokens(request, b)
    return JsonResponse(payload, status=status)
```

Comment: Why do you need transaction.atomic? You only save one object.

Comment: I can't make the object save the change of the count of access attempts so I tried everything, honestly

Comment: I propose you to use ready-to-use solution - `django-axes`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach that was my first attempt, then I decided to try with my own model but the behavior was the same in both cases